# Android: map fragment and sliding menu

Tags: android, google-maps, slidingmenu, mapfragment

so I m trying to add a sliding menu to a mapfragment activity that is displaying a google map. I have found some libraries for sliding menu on github but it's hard to use. Thus, I am wondering if there a a more feasible way (tutorials...) to add a sliding menu to a mapfragment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sliding menu or specifically sliding drawer ?

Comment: more like a sliding menu like the one in the facebook app. I want to use it to display a list of items.

Comment: then its obvious you will have to use available libs.